# Are named functions able to be shared?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-drive-sharing

I created a custom named function in Google sheets to simplify a really long formula. If I share this file, will the named function still work for the other user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named functions are automatically shared, because they are stored per spreadsheet, not per user. You can also import named functions from one spreadsheet file to another.

See the [named functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534) help page.